# Why does passing self by reference result in a bad access error?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c++11, lambda, signals

The following code snippet runs OK. I register the Objective-C function `mytestslot` as a callback for a signal originating in the C++ class `thing`. The slot function gets called periodically and everything is well behaved.

```
struct CPPMembers { // pimpl related stuff for C++ members
    Thing thing;
    boost::signals2::scoped_connection con;
};

@implementation MyChannelClass

-(void)mytestslot:(float)num{
    NSLog(@"Slot call = %0.2f", num);
}

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        //Allocate storage for C++ members
        _cppMembers = new CPPMembers;

        auto slotLambda = [self](float n){[self mytestslot:n];};
        _cppMembers->con =  _cppMembers->thing.addSubscriber(  slotLambda   );
    }


    return self;
}
...
```

However, when I change the `slotLambda` to capture by reference . .

```
auto slotLambda = [&](float n){[self mytestslot:n];};
```

I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at runtime when the signal is triggered. I'm guessing this might be due to a fundamental difference between Objective-C's `self` and C++'s `this` that I'm not grasping, but then I'm not entirely sure as I'm a total Objective-C newby!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a reference is a pointer to the variable disguised to behaves syntactically like the variable itself.

What is the address of `self`?  on the x86 architecture, it will be a parameter on the stack.  On arm and x64, it will be a register.  Either way, once the stack unwinds after `-init` returns, the reference will reference garbage.

Comment: Thanks, so what exactly is `self`? Is it heavy to pass by value if the class itself becomes more heavy, or is `self` just some kind of reference itself?

Comment: @learnvst: `self` is a local variable (it's a parameter) in methods. In any case, only local variables can be captured in lambdas.

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm still confused. The apple docs say explicitly that `self` is a pointer to the object 

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW5

The memory address contained by that pointer should be persistent no? I'm just confused as you can capture `this` by reference in C++ no problem.

Comment: @learnvst self is a pointer to a block of memory that contains the object state.  The block of memory is persistent, but you are not taking a reference to the block of memory, you are taking a reference to a *pointer* to the block of memory, a pointer that will go away as soon as the stack frame for the method unwinds.

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't have to do with `self` or Objective-C in particular.

It never makes sense in C++ to take a lambda that captures variables by reference and store it in a way that the lambda (or copy thereof) outlives the function it's created in.

This is because variables captured by lambdas (either by value or by reference) must be of automatic storage duration (i.e. local variables), and it is undefined behavior in C++ to access a reference after the variable it points to goes out of scope.